# How can I align two different-size pieces of text to the left and right while matching baselines?

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment

I am trying to change how the title and tagline are displayed in [the Coraline WordPress theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/coraline/).  I want them next to each other, aligned on their baseline, justified left and right.  I'm new to CSS.

I managed to figure out a solution, but it doesn't seem to work in Safari 8.  What is a robust alternative that works in recent versions of all major browsers?

This is my attempt that works in Chrome and Firefox:

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  /* This below is the key, doesn't work in Safari 8 */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
}

#title {
  font-size: 32pt;
  background: #aee;
}

#tagline {
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: #eea;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">Site Title</div>
  <div id="tagline">This is the tagline</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check if the Coraline theme works with Safari 8? If it works all you have to do is to copy the style of titles and taglines.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini The Coraline theme places the title and tagline one above the other.  I want to place them next to each other, as in the simplified example above.  The Coraline theme works well with Safari.  My modifications to it don't.  The question is only about my modifications.  I only mentioned Coraline for context, to explain why I want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari currently only supports [`flex`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) with prefix.

```
#container {
  display: -webkit-flex; /*new*/
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /*new*/
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline; /*new*/
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

**Updated demo:**

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  /* This below is the key, doesn't work in Safari 8
     Edit, added -webkit-* prefix */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
}

#title {
  font-size: 32pt;
  background: #aee;
}

#tagline {
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: #eea;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">Site Title</div>
  <div id="tagline">This is the tagline</div>
</div>
```

**Alternatively**, you could use `inline-block` with some tricks as follows.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0; /*fix for white space*/
}

#container:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#title, #tagline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#title {
  font-size: 32pt;
  background: #aee;
}

#tagline {
  font-size: 12pt;
  background: #eea;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">Site Title</div>
  <div id="tagline">This is the tagline</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks great!  Do you know if this works in recent versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Szabolcs IE11 native, IE10 with prefix, according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox